# How to see full search path for ES 6 import libraries

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I'm reading the code of a node application, and at the top of a file, I see an ES6-style import statement like

```
import Foobar from "foobar"
```

But I'm not sure where this `foobar` library is coming from.  There's not file called "foobar.js" in the project and there's not "foobar" library stated in the `package.json`.  Is it possible to see a comprehensive list of paths that the `import` directive searches?

Answer (score 2):

You can start searching for foobar, to see if npm knows about it :

```
npm ls foobar
```

If you use an IDE like vscode, you can ctrl+click to open it.

Answer (score 1):

By convention, a importing like

```
import Foobar from "foobar"
```

will import the `index.js` file from the `foobar` package found in your project's `node_modules` folder.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c) is a decryption how tow module of foo and bar are combined

```
function foo() {
  return 'bar';
}

function bar() {
 return 'foo';
}

module.exports.foo = foo;
module.exports.bar = bar;
```

there is an update of es6 module also check [here](https://hackernoon.com/node-js-tc-39-and-modules-a1118aecf95e)